# Dynamic Dropdown List giving PHP error Undefined Variable

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to create dynamic dropdowns for vehicle Makes and vehicle Models. I would like the user to be able to select the Make of vehicle in the first dropdown and then have the second dropdown populate the correlating Models for the vehicle Make that was selected. I have a CSV containing all of the vehicle Makes and Models - there are over 900 Models in the file. I have successfully got this working using only Javascript, but there are too many vehicle Models to code it this way.

I tried using PHP to read the CSV file and build an array and then echo out the Javascript code in a PHP foreach loop. If I run just the foreach loop in PHP, I can successfully echo out that portion of the Javascript code to an HTML page. However, as soon as I place the PHP code inside of a function and call the function in the page, I get an error. My troubleshooting leads me to believe that I need to use something like Ajax, but I am unfamiliar with Ajax and was hoping that I am close to a solution as-is, just need some insight on how to continue. Also, I didn't write the Javascript code here, I found it via a Google search. Although I do understand the basics, I am not very proficient with Javascript. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Javascript: this works as-is, but I do not want to have to enter 900 items like this:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function dynamicdropdown(listindex)
    {
        switch (listindex)
        {
        case "Acura" :
            document.getElementById("status").options[0]=new Option("Select","");
            document.getElementById("status").options[1]=new Option("CL","CL");
            document.getElementById("status").options[2]=new Option("Integra","Integra");
            document.getElementById("status").options[3]=new Option("Legend","Legend");

            break;
        case "Audi" :
            document.getElementById("status").options[0]=new Option("Select","");
            document.getElementById("status").options[1]=new Option("80","80");
            document.getElementById("status").options[2]=new Option("90","90");
            document.getElementById("status").options[3]=new Option("100","100");
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    </script>

    <div class="category_div" id="category_div">Make:
        <select id="source" name="source" onchange="javascript:dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value="">Select Make</option>
        <option value="Acura">Acura</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="sub_category_div" id="sub_category_div">Model:
        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        document.write('<select name="status" id="status"><option value="">Select status</option></select>')
        </script>
```

PHP: If I remove the function and just echo the results on the page, it builds the Javascript properly:

```
<?php

$filename = 'list.csv';

// The nested array to hold all the arrays
$vehicle_array = []; 

// Open the file for reading
if (($h = fopen("{$filename}", "r")) !== FALSE){
  // Each line in the file is converted into an individual array called $data
  // The items of the array are comma separated
  while (($data = fgetcsv($h, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE){
    // Each individual array is being pushed into the nested array
    $vehicle_array[] = $data;       
  }
  // Close the file
  fclose($h);
}

// Display the code in a format I can read
foreach ($vehicle_array as $row) {
    if ($row[2] == -1) {
        unset($vehicle_array[$row[2]]);
        echo 'break;';
    } elseif ($row[2] == 0) {
        echo 'case "';
        echo $row[0];
        echo '"  :';
        echo 'document.getElementById("status").options[';
        echo $row[2];
        echo ']=new Option("';
        echo $row[1];
        echo '","';
        echo "";
        echo '");'; 
    } else {
        echo 'document.getElementById("status").options[';
        echo $row[2];
        echo ']=new Option("';
        echo $row[1];
        echo '","';
        echo $row[1];
        echo '");';
    }
}
?>
```

This is where it breaks: I put the foreach loop inside a function and call the function later on the page to build that portion of the Javascript.

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function dynamicdropdown(listindex)
    {
        switch (listindex)
        {

        <?php buildForm(); ?>

        }
        return true;
    }
    </script>
```

I receive these errors:

1. Undefined Variable: vehicle_array
2. Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

---

Here is the error message straight out of Google Chrome:

function dynamicdropdown(listindex){switch (listindex){
**Notice**:  Undefined variable: vehicle_array in **C:\xampp\htdocs\test\drop.php** on line **25**

**Warning**:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in **C:\xampp\htdocs\test\drop.php** on line **25**

Please see image for full error messages. Again, any help here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again!

[Error messages in Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX7Hf.png)

[CSV file example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZs3I.png)

Comment: Which is the exact line where it breaks?

Comment: Where is the buildForm() function? You cannot call a php function from javascript or the other way around.

Comment: @Nawed Khan - thank you for the info. I was indeed trying to call the PHP function inside <script> tags. I changed it so that I build the entire script in PHP and then echo it on the page.... worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you attempt to use `$vehicle_array` in `buildForm` as a global variable, but you do not use the `global` keyword. There are two possible solutions:

#### Smart solution

Avoid using global variables whenever possible, so, in our case you will need to change two lines:

- the header of the function: `function buildForm($vehicle_array){`
- the calling of the function: `buildForm($vehicle_array);`

Choose this one. Please.

#### Not so smart solution

Before you use `$vehicle_array` in your `function` make sure it is used as a `global` variable with this line:

```
global $vehicle_array;
```

It might appear to be strange, but this is how the syntax works. Read more here: https://phppot.com/php/variable-scope-in-php/

Comment: That took care of the issue. I appreciate your help. Thank you!